How did the Sidekick TSR interfere with other programs?
Everybody remembers the wonderful DOS-pop up Sidekick, which provided a calculator, file manager, and ASCII table; plus other stuff I never used.

One reason it was wonderful is that it was always available no matter what other program you were running. But it was also famous for interfering with the operation of other software.
Sidekick was a Terminate And Stay Resident program. That means that it laid down on a slab and died, and would stay dead forever until somebody hit a key combination that woke it up like Sleeping Beauty.
Any keystroke woke it up, but it went back to sleep if it wasn't the Magic Kiss, Alt-Ctl. It ignored ones it didn't like.
The way that worked was, normally, the running program accepts all keyboard input. But sidekick is a clever TSR! To prevent other programs from hooking the keyboard vector and locking out sidekick from waking up, it had its friend,the highest-priority timer, prod sidekick periodically so it could grab the keyboard interrupt for itself. I suspect this was the cause of the famous incompatibility that killed sidekick. But I don't know. That's why I'm asking.
If a keystroke was not the hotkey, Sidekick  would merely return control to the running program that expected the input, and return itself to the dreamless void.
I have five questions.

Why did that screw things up? Why couldn't sidekick just process all keystrokes and pass the ones it wasn't interested into the app?

Did it involve processing additional keystrokes that occurred while sidekick was active? Was there something going on in the primary application that shouldn't be interrupted? Did some third process interrupt sidekick and mess up keystroke handling?

How often did sidekick rudely break in and steal the keyboard interrupt vector?  I assume it took the low level keyboard vector, right? I understand there's a higher, application-level interrupt also. But don't hold me to that.

Did Borland ever do anything to prevent this horrible well-known bug from manifesting? Like, did they increase the frequency with which it grabbed the interrupt vector?

What happened when the bug occurred. Did it crash the app, or the system, or hang it, or what?

Why didn't they just use the SysReq hotkey? This is specifically the kind of thing that SysReq was invented for, and it was completely ignored by DOS and apps.


It occurs to me that one possible problem might be that the that the hotkey was Ctrl-Alt, so the pressed state of the control and alt keys have to be remembered between key presses. That synchronization might have caused problems when repeatedly reinitializing the keyboard handler. But that's just a bug, something to be fixed in version 1.1.
If I were programming Sidekick, the proper interrupt-vector retake frequency would be a VERY interesting question!
Too frequently, and you kill the performance of the computer. But I can't see what a too-infrequent grabbing of the interrupt would do except pass the hotkey to an application that didn't expect it.
Is that what caused applications to crash when sidekick was running? Surely it can't be that simple!

If you periodically hook the keyboard interrupt vector for a moment, it's useless. Either the vector gets executed from some keyboard event, or not. Hooking the vector for a moment every once in a while cannot detect if hotkey combo for activating a TSR has already been pressed if it was not pressed while being hooked. Where does the assumption comes from that that's the way it worked? Your other questions seem to have similar weird assumptions how things worked, why not simply ask how
things work, instead of asking how it worked with a seemingly impossble assumption about it?

You’re making a number of assumptions. “Terminate and stay resident” doesn’t mean what you seem to think it means; there’s no need for a separate module to wake the main module up. SIdekick did intercept all keystrokes, that’s the only way a key-activated TSR can work. And most importantly, you allude to a famous bug without explaining what it was, which makes it hard to answer your question(s)…

@justme Thank you for making me aware that I need to add more information to the question. I assumed that people knew how sidekick worked. The reason it continually retook the vector was because another program might have hooked it. Sidekick wanted to always  be in control, and never ever reset the vector to its previous value. The  core of all my questions is the consequences of having to retake the vector all the time.

@MissUnderstands OK fine but there's several methods to do that. If you disassemble the sidekick then we can read how it worked. For example a game that runs in graphics mode may not be able to recover back to custom graphics mode if Sidekick goes to text mode and does not know how to recreate the custom graphics mode.

@Justme Yes, that was the nature of the incompatibility that doomed sidekick! After looking up something that I figured other people would already know, graphics interrupt handling involved saving the graphics image so it can be restored. This required allocating enough memory for the largest possible image, even if the user only ever ran notepad. This became more difficult and costly as graphic standards improved. So that's a second reason. Quick Google results are mostly about Lotus and software suite graphics mode. I was hoping someone here would know all these reasons, but oh well.

@MissUnderstands SideKick only needs to restore the data it replaces, which is at most a full screen of text-mode data; that’s 4000 bytes, no need to allocate more than that.

It doesn't surprise me that a program that goes to great lengths to hijack system mechanisms ends up dicking things up.

With a question that broad, an answer can only be as broad: By running on the same computer, using the same resources, without an OS managing them.

Much of it comes down to this: making TSRs cooperate reasonably was a matter of them all following conventions. But almost all conventions were established after Sidekick was written, because Sidekick was what established TSRs as meaningful and useful. Previously, the DOS TSR function had been seen more as a curiosity than the foundation of a useful type of program.

Well, that's not how TSRs work.
If a TSR wants to check when some keycombo gets pressed, it needs to hook the vector for itself to check each key event from keyboard to see if all the keys in the keycombo are now pushed or the sequence of keys has been entered.
And as with all DOS programs, they expect that they are the only program running on the machine.
If there is a TSR that activates in the middle of some important operation or otherwise at an extremely inconvenient moment, any program may fail to perform what it was supposed to do properly.
Depending on what a TSR does and how it does it, the other programs may or may not tolerate it.
There are as many reasons as there are programs that don't like TSRs to get activated during their execution.
There are also many methods how a TSR might always want to stay on top of the keyboard interrupt chain, each bringing in their own problems.
The TSR could hook DOS functions that games use to hook interrupt vectors. But this cannot detect programs that access the vector table directly.
The TSR could periodically check for changes in interrupt vector table. And hope that a vector has fully changed when it decides it has changed. If a game disables keyboard interrupt via the interrupt controller, it might be in the middle of changing the vector in memory when TSR looks for updated address and then it reads the vector address wrong.
The TSR could reprogram the hardware vector table to be somewhere else in memory, and install trampolines to jump to execute original vector. Then the original program has no way of making sure the vector it has installed runs as expected directly. If the program does weird things itself with the interrupts, it expects to work as usual instead of some other program already making weird things with them.
For instance there is only a handful of software interrupts reserved for user software, int 60h..int 67h. Some games might basically use e.g int 60h or 61h for a music driver, and if that is already in use for network packet driver or some other TSR, expect issues.
The most usual problem I have found when keyboard interrupts is that the keyboard controller keeps the scancode available for a limited time.
This was not a problem in PCs before AT, as the CPU can read the scancode input port as many times it wants and hold the keyboard from sending the next scancode for as long as necessary and let the original game code acknowledge the keyboard to continue.
With ATs and more modern PCs, the keyboard interrupt is basically acknowledged by reading the scan code, and the controller is free to stop displaying it or present the next available scancode. There is no mechanism to peek the scancode without removing it from buffer, or read the previously read scancode again if new scancodes have already arrived.
Therefore any man-in-the-middle keyboard vector hooking is very difficult subject, and thus many programs that hook the vector for themselves may have issues working with a TSR that has already hooked the keyboard interrupt.
In such a case there might be already three levels that want the scan codes, the game, the TSR, the BIOS, and if the TSR tries to inject itself to be the first again as the new first level vector, the chain is already 4 levels deep, and the game could spend too much time in the keyboard handler for the whole chain to work, each handler reading the scancode separately from the keyboard controller.
And corrupted screens are another thing. A game/program may have set a custom graphics mode and the TSR cannot know that. At least unless it knows which type of video adapter you have, and type is such that the current state of video adapter can be fully retrieved and fully set again to continue the original game/program. And it is literally impossible to have drivers to support each and all video cards with diferent chipsets to simply do a TSR. For basic case like VGA without any extensions, surely possible, and many "game wizard" kind of TSR programs to add health or ammo worked with most games.

Aww, that was FASCINATING! That's what I come here for. Just one example, "there is only a handful of software interrupts reserved for user software, int 60h..int 67h." === I didn't know there were only 2 user vectors on the 8088. That explained why it was such a big deal when the 286 doubled the vector table. I didn't appreciate it at that time. I figured there were plenty of others, what's the big deal? I thought of the TV show, 8 is enough. I never thought I would find out why. And that was just one example. Thank you! === See guys, remember the joy.

@MissUnderstands You are mixing concepts and jumping to conclusions. The CPUs only reserve a handful of vectors (say 8 on 8088, 16 on 286) for division by zero and protected mode exceptions etc. The problem is, when 286 cpu was put in, some vectors were already used for other than CPU exceptions. And you could not move the hardware interrupts for keeping compatibility. After CPU and BIOS and DOS, the PC as a whole has reseerved for user only 8 vectors, 60h to 67h. Of which EMM then took 67h.

Yeah, that's cool and interesting. But I already knew you can steal them from other processes and share them as long as they're not hardware interrupts. I just didn't know that there were only 2 user vectors available. === But: "You are mixing concepts and jumping to conclusions." Where the hell did that come from, the hostility? I can't read minds like you non-autistics. I'm sure it's obvious to everybody else. And of course, there's always the possibility that it's not hostility at all. But I can't tell, see?

@MissUnderstands 60h to 67h is a range of 8. You mixed the CPU interrupts with how they are used on the PC which is a machine running BIOS API and DOS or other OS on the CPU. And you drew conclusions from my answer that are not true, my answer does not explain why 286 doubling the vector table was a big deal. 8088 and 286 CPU have both 224 interrupts available for user. BIOS, DOS, programs use them, reserving them for some or no or future purpose, while leaving 8 reserved for users, of which EMM and network driver, other TSRs may use, leaving even less free.

“And hope that a vector has fully changed when it decides it has changed.” That shouldn’t be a problem in practice, because any TSR changing the IVT without disabling interrupts would run into trouble sooner or later. “The TSR could reprogram the hardware vector table to be somewhere else in memory” — on an 8086?

@StephenKitt That comment was based on the obscure idea that the TSR would somehow (maybe in a timer interrupt) periodically check/change keyboard vector to itself, and it would fail if timer interrupt gets executed while the original program does not disable interrupts globally so the TSR executes in the middle. And yes, the 8259 can be reprogmmed where the hardware vectors are, so if TSR reprograms the 8259 and installs hooks to call original vectors, no other program can intercept it.

@Justme ah right, I misinterpreted the vector table as referring to the full IVT, not the IRQs! As far as your first idea is concerned, that’s what I had understood — but it seems to me that a TSR setting a vector without disabling interrupts would have a good chance of running afoul of other interrupts, enough at least to cause problems for some users, even without some other TSR trying to modify the vectors itself in a timer interrupt…

When SideKick is installed, it hooks a number of interrupts:

0x08, the system timer interrupt
0x09, the “keyboard data ready” interrupt
0x10, the BIOS video service entrypoint
0x13, the BIOS disk service entrypoint
0x16, the BIOS keyboard service entrypoint
0x1C, the system timer tick
0x21, the main DOS API entrypoint
0x25, “absolute disk read”
0x26, “absolute disk write”
0x28, the DOS idle interrupt

When a key is pressed, interrupt 0x09 is called; the TSR “convention” is then that the first handler checks whether the key is relevant to it, and if not, chains to the next handler. All other key handling stems from that interrupt, including SysRq; so a TSR hooking interrupt 0x09 wouldn’t benefit from only using SysRq.
Obviously the order here is important in case of conflict, and this might be where a TSR author would want to “re-hook” an interrupt: by ensuring that it gets first dibs on a keystroke, it ensures that it’s the first to be allowed to handle relevant keys. This is especially important for SideKick since it relies on modifier keys only (combinations of Ctrl, Alt, and the two Shift keys). I haven’t checked what SideKick actually does, but some of its other hooks would allow it to do this if it wanted to.
The keyboard hook might be where most of the issues occur. For example, in some programs SideKick’s keys don’t pop it up until the next “real” key is pressed: pressing CtrlAlt or both Shift keys doesn’t pop SideKick up, but the next key after that does. Quarterdeck’s Manifest exhibits this behaviour with SideKick.
As far as frequency goes, hooking an interrupt is a near-zero-cost operation, there would hardly be any performance impact (compared to actually being invoked by an interrupt in the first place). All you need to do is copy two words somewhere safe (to chain to the next handler) and write two words (to set the interrupt vector); if SideKick did re-hook interrupts, things would get a little more complex since it would have to remember a chain of next handlers, but that’s not too hard to deal with either.
You mentioned in a (now deleted) comment that the bug you remembered was that SideKick would corrupt graphics screens. That was a problem in the initial release, fixed in most cases in version 1.56A (which is the version I used to get the list of hooked interrupts above). SideKick appears to deal with graphics screens by hooking interrupt 0x10, and remembering the settings used for the last “set video mode” call. When invoked, it would restore text mode (optionally blanking the graphics), and then when returning to the currently-running program, restore the previous mode by calling interrupt 0x10 with the stored settings, with the high bit of AL set to avoid clearing the screen. This would work in circumstances where the graphics mode was set entirely through interrupt 0x10, and SideKick knew the corresponding memory layout; it would fail with programs that directly manipulated the graphics registers. Significantly, restoring the screen doesn’t require a variable amount of storage depending on the graphics mode; SideKick assumes that all it needs to do is save and restore the storage required for the text-mode buffer (4000 bytes).
So to answer your titular question, SideKick can interfere with other programs by preventing them from getting keyboard input they expect, by incorrectly restoring their display, and like any TSR, by taking too much time during timer ticks. All that’s theoretical, I haven’t checked whether SideKick actually does interfere with programs in these ways.

Thank you! That's the most complete, interesting answer that I've ever had on stack exchange. I wish I could only get answers like yours instead of all the bs drama.

By the way, how in the world did you find out which interrupts sidekick hooked? Do you have the documentation or did you run it in a debugger or can you tell from the entry points names in the dll, or what?

I loaded SideKick and looked at the interrupt vector table; I listed the interrupts pointing at SideKick’s allocated memory. An easier option is to load SideKick and run Quarterdeck Manifest (available with QEMM) and check the “Interrupts” screen.

Damn that's cool! After I asked, I thought it was a stupid question because It occurred to me that you probably just  found it online. Security classes were really cool too. You got to dissect professionally written government viruses, to watch their amazing modular structure and how they write to the very lowest level hardware.

Did you do this on an 8088? I'm just curious.

I have an 8088 (and a bunch of other old PCs), but in this instance I just ran SideKick in a PC emulator.

Dos box lets you look at the virtual interrupt table? Do you just run debug in the virtual machine?

Any DOS environment (whether it’s a virtual machine, or a full-blown emulator, or DOS running on a physical system) lets you see the interrupt table. And yes, when I wrote this answer I just ran DEBUG in the emulator (in my case, DOSEMU, not DOSBox).

Your assumption on "if SideKick did re-hook interrupts, things would get a little more complex since it would have to remember a chain of next handlers, but that’s not too hard to deal with either." seems to be a bit optimistic to me: Even if additional programs would follow all conventions (like storing and calling the "old" handler and re-instating it when terminating), remembering chains of interrupts in a TSR is not helpful: There's no notification when a "follow-up" TSR unhooks itself, so you're always working on potentially out-dated information.

@tofro Yes that's a consideration, and it would be an important one if I were writing sidekick. But in real life, how often are TSRs nested? And of those, how many rehook the interrupt vector? I guess it would happen if your product was in every PC in the world.

@StephenKitt > DOSEMU, not DOSBox === Which is better? I only need a one bit answer, so I can just download it without having to compare them. If they're equivalent, then the hell with it. Does DOSEMU let you install device drivers?

@tofro the issue I had in mind is that if you start off with a typical SK → KEYB → BIOS chain for interrupt 9 for example, then something else comes along and hooks it, and SK wants to re-hook it, it needs to remember the chain itself (SK → foo → SK → KEYB → BIOS) so it can handle it correctly when it’s invoked the second time around. Unhooking is a problem, but well-behaved TSRs are supposed to not unhook themselves if they are no longer the “head” hook. Where things get interesting is with non-TSRs hooking interrupts, for example XyWrite with its specific keyboard handler.

@tofro there are ways to deal with all that but it does get increasingly complex — for example when hooking or re-hooking the vector you could also store the MCB information for the block containing the previous hook (if it has an MCB), which would allow you to check that it’s still valid. So I guess “not too hard to deal with” is indeed optimistic!

@MissUnderstands they serve different purposes. If you want to play with device drivers, DOSEMU is better, but you might as well go for something more modern like PCem or 86Box. I use DOSEMU because I’m familiar with it and I have a nice working setup, but I’ve been using it for thirty years; someone starting out now would be better off with something newer.

@StephenKitt .PCem or 86Box. === Do you have a preference? If Dosbox is obsolete, I just need to know what to use instead. ty.
